# How to create html element dynamically with props based on `as` on react (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to create a, b, div or another element based on `as={""}` prop in my function.

I am checking `as` and then use if guards to create element one-by-one. But is there any way to create html element based on as component?

I want to be able to create `b, a, h4 h3` or any element without `if`'s

I've found similar question but it uses styled components. Is it possible to do it without it?

Currently im doing this:

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface Props {
  children: (React.ReactChild | React.ReactNode) | (React.ReactChild[] | React.ReactNode[])
  onClick?: (e) => void
  as?: string
}

const DynElement: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = props => {
  const { as , children } = props

  return (
  <>
    {as === 'div' && <div {...props_rest}>
      {children}
    </div>}
    {as === 'b' && <b {...props_rest}>
      {children}
    </b>}
    </>
  )
}

export default DynElement
```

and usage is:

```
<DynElement as="b" onClick={...}>...</DynElement>
```

Using TypeScript + React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the `as` prop in an uppercase variable and use that as a JSX component:

```
const { as: Cmp = ‘div’, ...rest } = props;

return (
  <Cmp {...rest} />
);
```

No need to even pass children explicitly. It will be passed along with the ‘rest’ props.

Comment: This gave me errors on TypeScript. Perhaps will work for JSX but on TSX I get: ```Type '{ children: string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ... 55 more ... | (ReactNode[] & ReactPortal); ... 8 more ...; as?: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559)```

Comment: And, If I give `as: any` instead of `string`, this time it throws an error:  `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Comment: Ah no! I forgot to declare as on source :) Sorry. This is correct. I didn't know we could do like this. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: Are you using this component without passing the “as” prop? If so you’d need to have it default to a div (or whatever). I’ll update my answer to provide a div fallback.

Comment: Updated. Now defaults to div if the prop isn’t provided.

Comment: Exactly. I forgot to add as={} on other file. Didn't realize that for a while :). Anyway, I did default value if none given. So everything works now. Default is `div` if not given anything. I also changed string to strict types like `'div' | 'span' | 'a' | null...`